# Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-1,3)$ using the definition of UC.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

$$f(x)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{x} & x\neq 0 \\
      \frac{1}{4} & x=0
\end{array} 
\right.$$
Either $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq0$, $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$, $x\neq 0$ and $y=0$, or $x=0$ and $y=0$ (I have already proved cases 2, 3, and 4). If $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, then $\forall \ \varepsilon>0$ pick $\displaystyle\delta=\min\{1,\text{Something else with } \varepsilon\}$ so that if $x,y\in(-1,3)\backslash\{0\}$ and $|x-y|<\delta$ then
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=\left| \frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{x}-\frac{2-\sqrt{4-y}}{y}\right|=\left| \frac{2y-y\sqrt{4-x}-2x+x\sqrt{4-y}}{xy}\right|$$
since $x,y\in(-1,3)$, we have $-x\leq 1$ and $-y\leq 1$
$$\leq \left| \frac{2(y-x)+\sqrt{4+1}(x-y)}{xy}\right|$$
since $\delta\leq 1$ we have $x-1<y$ and $y-1<x$...

It was at this point when I had set my delta as $\displaystyle\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{9\varepsilon}{2+\sqrt{5}}\right\}$, that I realized I was maximizing my denominator making the function smaller rather than larger. I don't see a way to continue down this route as I can pick $x$ and $y$ to be arbitrarially small. What did I miss here? I have since been playing around with rationalizing my denominator and adding possibly adding in $+1/4-1/4$ to try and simplify, but I can't quite get it.

Edit 1: I don't think this can be proven in the direction I took because I basically have 
$$\left|\frac{x-y}{xy}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right|$$
and this is the same proof for $f=1/x$ which is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$\frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{x}=\frac{\left(2-\sqrt{4-x}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{4-x}\right)}{x\left(2+\sqrt{4-x}\right)}=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4-x}} $$
and
$$\begin{align}
\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}-\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4-y}}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{\sqrt{4-y}-\sqrt{4-x}}{\left(2+\sqrt{4-x}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{4-y}\right)}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{x-y}{\left(2+\sqrt{4-x}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{4-y}\right)\left(\sqrt{4-x}+\sqrt{4-y}\right)}\right| \\
&= \frac{|x-y|}{\left(2+\sqrt{4-x}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{4-y}\right)\left(\sqrt{4-x}+\sqrt{4-y}\right)}
\end{align} $$
Notice that each of the square roots are $>1$. Hence, 
$$\left(2+\sqrt{4-x}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{4-y}\right)\left(\sqrt{4-x}+\sqrt{4-y}\right)>3\cdot 3\cdot 2=18 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{|x-y|}{\left(2+\sqrt{4-x}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{4-y}\right)\left(\sqrt{4-x}+\sqrt{4-y}\right)}\leq \frac{|x-y|}{18} $$
So, choosing $\delta_1=\varepsilon$ works. The final choice of $\delta$ should be $\min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3)$ where the different deltas are for each of the three cases (for the 4th one, any choice works).

Comment: Oh my, I was so close to that, I knew the denominator could be a number, but the I was stuck on the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quicker way using the fact that a function that is continuous on a compact set $M$ is also uniformly continuous on $M$ (this is called [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)).

Check that $f$ is continuous on $[-1,3]$ by checking that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1/4$ (continuity at the other points is obvious). Thus, it's also uniformly continuous on $[-1,3]$. A function that is uniformly continuous on a set $A$ is uniformly continuous on any subset of $A$. The claim then follows.

Comment: I believe we can only use the definition of uniform continuity to prove this, though that is very nice to know

Comment: @drfrankie certainly, there's a proof using the definition directly. It wasn't clear to me whether you're asking for such proofs only.

Comment: Oh, sorry i should have said that my b.